# combine two different model fields in form.py in django

Tags: django, forms

**models.py**

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyname = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique = True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')

class KeywordCache(models.Model):
    keyword = models.ForeignKey('Keyword')
    testcase = models.ForeignKey('TestcaseCache')


class TestcaseCache(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary = models.TextField()
    pre_requisite = models.TextField(blank = True)
    steps = models.TextField()
    expected_results = models.TextField()
    post_test = models.TextField(blank = True)
    data_provider = models.TextField(blank = True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Engineer, related_name = 'author_id')
    reviewer = models.ForeignKey(Engineer,related_name = 'reviewer_id',null=True,blank = True,default=None)
    release = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank = True)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    bugs = models.TextField(blank = True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank = True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project')
    feature = models.ForeignKey('FeatureCache')
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from apps.tcg.models import TestcaseCache
from apps.tcg.models import Keyword
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms import ModelForm

# Create the form class.


class TestcaseCacheForm(forms.ModelForm),KeywordForm(models.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = TestcaseCache,Keyword
        fields = ('name','package_name','summary','pre_requisite','steps','expected_results','post_test','data_provider','author','reviewer','release',keyname,'bugs','notes','project','feature')
```

**views.py**

```
from forms import TestcaseCacheForm

    def createForm(request):
        return render(request,'tcgform.html',{'form':TestcaseCacheForm(),'testcase_object_array':testcase_object_array,'author_name':author_name,'project_name':project_id,'feature_name':feature_name})
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: My question is how to combine two diff fields of two diff models in one Form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ModelForms don't allow you to inherit more than one model class, however, a view is indifferent to the number of form classes it can process. To the end user, you could present two form classes combined in one HTML form. Example, assuming you have two model form classes:

```
def my_view(request):
    keyword_form = KeywordForm(request.POST or None)
    another_form = AnotherForm(request.POST or None)

    if keyword_form.is_valid and another_form.is_valid():
        # do whatever

    return render(request, 'your-template.html',
        {'keyword_form': keyword_form, 'another_form': another_form})


# your_template.html
<form action="." method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <ul>
        {{ keyword_form.as_ul }}
        {{ another_form.as_ul }}
    </ul>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Of course, if you need exacting control over what fields go where, you can always define your field locations instead of using the quick and dirty rendering. Hope that helps you out.